# Invalid expression term '>'

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 with .NET 2.0. I have a comboBox that I use to select a product. After I select a product I am searching for it in a text file – in the end I want to find the line of that product in the file. However with the following code

```
int lineNo = lineList.IndexOf(lineList.Find(x => x.StartsWith(select)));
```

the compiler gives the error :

```
Invalid expression term '>'
```

Is this a problem with the 2.0 framework version of .NET?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I have using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 with 2.0 Net.

That means you're using C# 2.

But you're trying to use a lambda expression (`=>`) - a feature introduced in C# 3. It's not the version of the *framework* that you're using - you could write the same code in VS2008 or later, still targeting .NET 2. It's the version of the *language* you're using.

You can do something similar in C# 2 with an anonymous method though:

```
int lineNo = lineList.IndexOf(lineList.Find(delegate(String x)
{ 
   return x.StartsWith(select);
}));
```

Comment: Yes. So I must look for other way?

Comment: so that's what you expect from half-a-milion-reputation user: not only a mere explanation why not works - but also a proper workaround. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Lambda expression are supported starting version `3.0` of the `C#` language.  The `framework 2.0  + Vs 2005` pair uses the `c# 2.0`.